# How to delete text before another text on every line

Tags: text, oauth, token, notepad++, notepad

I have a list with `oauth's`, i have the format `username:oauth:token`, I need to get only tokens removing username and the `oauth` text on each line, like from `UserCool:oauth:djhjwfjfwjfjwfj` to djhjwfjfwjfjwfj, the problem is that i need to do that on every line so I cant just do remove everything before, how can I do it? (every software)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/mDVQ7.png

Comment: [Please post your data as text, not image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/372239).

Comment: [Edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69678980/edit) and add sample text **and expected result**.

Answer (score 1):

Notepad++ is good for doing this one-shot

**Screenshot of the Notepad++ "Replace" window** :

[image: Screenshot of the Notepad++ "Replace" window]

Here are the steps to follow:

1. Enter the expression `^.\*:.\*:` inside the "Find What" text box
2. Enter an empty string in the "Replace With" textbox
3. select the Search Mode "Regular Expression"
4. click on "Replace All"

Comment: This will not work if there is colon `:` in the token.

Comment: You are right @Toto, I was under the assumption that the token ought not to contain them.

In this case, you need a non greedy regex like the one that follows
^.\*?:.\*?: